# How to count number of times the primary key of a row is referenced in a specific table with Objection.js

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, orm, objection.js

(Using PostgreSQL)
So, I have these (User and Vote) Objection.js models:

```js
const { Model } = require('objection');

class User extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return 'users';
  }
  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      posts: {
        relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
        modelClass: require('./Post'),
        join: {
          from: 'users.id',
          to: 'posts.userId',
        },
      },
      comments: {
        relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
        modelClass: require('./Comment'),
        join: {
          from: 'users.id',
          to: 'comments.userId'
        }
      },
      votes: {
        relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
        modelClass: require('./Vote'),
        join: {
          from: 'users.id',
          to: 'votes.userId'
        }
      }
    };
  }
}

module.exports = User;
```

```js
const { Model } = require('objection');

class Vote extends Model {
  static get tableName () { return 'votes' }
  static get relationalMappings () {
    return {
      user: {
        relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
        modelClass: require('./User'),
        join: {
          from: 'votes.userId',
          to: 'users.id'
        }
      },
      post: {
        relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
        modelClass: require('./Post'),
        join: {
          from: 'votes.postId',
          to: 'posts.id'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports = Vote;
```

The psql command `\d users` returns:

```
                              Table "public.users"
   Column    |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |      Default
-------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------
 id          | uuid                   |           | not null | gen_random_uuid()
 username    | character varying(128) |           | not null |
 displayname | character varying(128) |           | not null |
 email       | character varying(256) |           | not null |
 description | character varying(256) |           |          |
 password    | character varying(512) |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "users_id_index" btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "comments" CONSTRAINT "comments_userid_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("userId") REFERENCES users(id)
    TABLE "posts" CONSTRAINT "posts_userid_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("userId") REFERENCES users(id)
    TABLE "votes" CONSTRAINT "votes_userid_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("userId") REFERENCES users(id)
```

And the psql command `\d votes` returns:

```
                    Table "public.votes"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |      Default
--------+---------+-----------+----------+-------------------
 id     | uuid    |           | not null | gen_random_uuid()
 userId | uuid    |           | not null |
 postId | uuid    |           | not null |
 up     | boolean |           | not null |
 down   | boolean |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "votes_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "votes_id_index" btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "votes_postid_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("postId") REFERENCES posts(id)
    "votes_userid_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("userId") REFERENCES users(id)
```

What i would like to do is use some sort of Model class method (on the class User) to set the properties `upvotes` (number of Votes with `up` set to true), `downvotes` (number of Votes with `down` set to true) and `balance` (`upvotes - downvotes`).

Comment: so you want to count the balance of a specific user ?

Comment: @AbedMurrar Yeah

Comment: @AbedMurrar It's just I don't know how i would implement it into a class method

Comment: you can make a query for each user like `const myUserId=2; const {raw} = require('objection'); 
await Vote.query().select('userId', raw('(SUM(up = true) - SUM(down = true))').as('balance')).groupBy('userId').where('userId',myUserId).first()`

Comment: @AbedMurrar Apparently i can't use a boolean value in the SUM function, so...

Comment: can you try using 1 and 0 instead of true and false